# after Bios screen appears, the purple screen appears with a red circle and a white line through it, saying cannot load Ubuntu 2D

Tags: 2d

After the Bios screen appears, the purple screen appears and says, "cannot load Ubuntu2D" Log off. Logging off is my only option. I am operating on a Dell Insoirion 11.10 Ubuntu system. I deleted the gnome because I read in the forum it slowed down the computer and I wanted to watch movies. I deleted Unity as well because I read terrible things about it and that it was not necessary for me. I realize my experimention in learning by adding and deleting things were not proper. I was just trying to learn and fix my sound. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So If I understand correctly you seemed to have removed gnome and unity. And now you get a message saying Unity 2D doesn't load. **Please do not remove stuff if you do not understand the importance of it.** It is difficult to understand your scenario, but you seemed to have removed major components of your desktop.

You can try installing Unity back again by following the steps below,

1. Press Ctrl+F1 to enter into the tty terminal.
2. Login into your account by entering your credentials.
3. Type `sudo apt-get install unity`
4. Then type `sudo reboot`. Enter the password and reboot your computer
5. You should now be able to login into your desktop using Unity

However I strongly recommend that you reinstall Ubuntu on your system since you might have removed other important packages.

Tip: Do not follow instructions on the web without understanding them. If you had asked on AskUbuntu, you wouldn't have faced this issue. My personal recommendation is to stick with Unity (it is good by the way), use it and the judge it yourself instead of what you read on the internet. And once you are comfortable and know in and outs of Ubuntu then try experimenting with it.